# Is it possible to invoke card.io library from a web based application?

Tags: card.io

I want to use card.io library for scanning credit card and retrieve details in a web based application. Is it possible to invoke card.io using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, card.io was designed and built for a mobile-only use case.